Fontspec fails to find .ttf file at specified path Windows
I have a custom font in a .ttf file saved say at this path: "D:/CustomFonts/myFont.ttf"
I therefore try to do something as follows:
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,final]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ Path =D:/CustomFonts/]{MyFont.ttf}

 \begin{document}
 \section{My Section}
 This is some interesting text where I say some things.
 \end{document}

However this gives the following errors:
warning: open of input [D:/CustomFonts/MyFont.ttf]/OT failed
caused by: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)
error: FontTesting.tex:8: Package fontspec Error: The font "MyFont" cannot be found.

If I place the MyFont.ttf file in the same directory as my TeX file and just not have the whole Path = some path thing, then it works as expected.
But ideally, I don't have to copy all of the fonts I want to use into my current directory.
I don't think I have seen the issue fixed for windows anywhere.
edit: I compile using tectonic

I can't reproduce error 123, but can reproduce "The font cannot be found". Adding / to the end of the path helps (D:/CustomFonts/). Compiles by xelatex or lualatex from TeXLive 2023 on Windows 10.

@SergeiGolovan That was a typo. I have the extra slash at the end, and still get the error that it cannot find my font.

You should probably raise that with the tectonic developers
